# Three.js toShapes() moved to new class in v81, how to access it

Tags: javascript, three.js

I've updated Three.js from v73 to v81. 
I'm getting this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: path.toShapes is not a function

On looking at the [release documents](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/pull/9079), I found:

Changes to Path:

- got rid of .actions (yay)
- getPoints() moved to CurvePath
- toShapes() moved to new class ShapePath

My code segment is this:

```
var shapes = [];
for (var i = 0; i < paths.length; ++i) {
    // Turn each SVG path into a three.js shape
    var path = d3.transformSVGPath( paths[i] );
    // We may have had the winding order backward.
    **var newShapes = path.toShapes(effectController.reverseWO);**
    // Add these three.js shapes to an array.
    shapes = shapes.concat(newShapes);
}
```

I could not find THREE.Path anywhere so I imported [Path.js](https://threejsdoc.appspot.com/doc/three.js/src.source/extras/core/Path.js.html) in case it would help, but to no avail. I'm new to Three.js so do not know if it's a noob question, but I've been at it for a day now and cannot figure it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [ShapePath](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/extras/core/ShapePath) class contains the method you are looking for: [.toShapes()](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/extras/core/ShapePath.toShapes).  The [example](https://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_geometry_extrude_shapes2) the documentation links to also [utilizes this method](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/examples/webgl_geometry_extrude_shapes2.html#L298):

```
path = $d3g.transformSVGPath( thePaths[i] );
...
simpleShapes = path.toShapes(true);
```

The issue is that the [d3-threeD](https://github.com/asutherland/d3-threeD/blob/master/lib/d3-threeD.js#L14) source that includes the `.transformSVGPath()` method still defines `var path = new THREE.Shape();`.

Notice in the [example](https://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_geometry_extrude_shapes2), that there is a [snippet of code](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/examples/webgl_geometry_extrude_shapes2.html#L46) that is taken/derived from d3-threeD, but is updated to use `THREE.ShapePath()`:

```
...
function transformSVGPath(pathStr) {
    var path = new THREE.ShapePath();
...
```

I would recommend you follow the example source and include the updated `.transformSVGPath()` method which uses `THREE.ShapePath()`.